# ConfigParser и Словарь Integer

Tags: python

на текущий момент читаю словари из файла:

```
global Size; Size = Cfg.Read(self, 'Size')

class Cfg:
    def Read(self, sections):
        self.cp = ConfigParser()
        self.cp.read(file)
        sections = self.cp[sections]
        return sections
```

в file:

```
[Size]
width = 1920
height = 1080
border = 1
icon = 30
indent = 172
backlight = 2
```

в результате у переменных вместо значения int (0, 1, 2) получается тип str ('1', '2', '3') и приходится каждый элемент отдельно переводить в int...

есть ли возможность используя словари прочитать значения именно int ?

может что-то такое:

```
out1 = self.cp[sections]
out2 = out1[key, int(out1[key])]
return out2
```

Comment: `return dict([key, int(sections[key]) for key in sections])`?

Comment: читаю целиком группу [Size] с параметрами.... и создаю словарь Size с параметрами. (Целиком)

Answer (score 1):

[configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

```
a_float = config.getfloat('Section1', 'a_float')
an_int = config.getint('Section1', 'an_int')
print(a_float + an_int)
```

Comment: в данном случае an_int = 15 находится в разделе [Section1]. Получается читая an_int из [Section1] мы преобразуем в getint.  Мне же нужно, чтобы не зная имени элемента "an_int" я мог создать массив всех элементов Section1 значение которых при этом должно быть int.

Answer (score 1):

спасибо, ответ нашел самостоятельно:

```
out = {}
for name, value in self.cp.items(sections):
    out.update([(name, int(value))])
return out
```